# Attempt to de-reference a null object -- while querying OrderItem

Tags: apex, visualforce, wrapper-class

I am creating a vf page where a user can create multiple orderitem for a order by adding dynamic rows.

When a user selects any product from product lookup, i have an actionsupport which will query product2 and populate values like productcode, unit price.

But after selecting the product i am getting **Attempt to de-reference a null object**

```
 **Getting errr at this line**          wrapper.odi.Product2 = [Select ProductCode,Name ,Family ,description ,(Select UnitPrice, Product2Id From PricebookEntries) From Product2 where Id = :wrapper.odi.Product2Id];
```

error

Below is the code

Apex class -

```
  public class CreateOrders {

        public Order order{get;set;}
        public List<orderitemclass> otlist {get;set;}
        public Pricebook2 standardBook;
        public OrderItem oti;
        public String wrapperId { get; set; }
        public String changedPosRevWrapperId { get; set; }

         public CreateOrders(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
             order = new Order();
             oti = new OrderItem();
             otlist = new List<orderitemclass>();
             otlist.add(new orderitemclass(oti));
             standardBook = [SELECT Id FROM Pricebook2 WHERE IsStandard = true];
         }
        private orderitemclass getrfpWrapper(String wrapperId) {
            for (orderitemclass rfpWrapper : otlist){
                if (rfpWrapper.wrapperId == wrapperId)

                    return rfpWrapper;
            }
            return null;
        }
        public void productdetails(){
            orderitemclass wrapper = getrfpWrapper(changedPosRevWrapperId);
  **Getting errr at this line**          wrapper.odi.Product2 = [Select ProductCode,Name ,Family ,description ,(Select UnitPrice, Product2Id From PricebookEntries) From Product2 where Id = :wrapper.odi.Product2Id];
        }
        public class orderitemclass{
            public OrderItem odi {get; set;}
            public String wrapperId { get; set; }
            public orderitemclass(OrderItem ot){
                odi = new OrderItem();
                odi = ot;
                Blob b = Crypto.GenerateAESKey(128);
                String h = EncodingUtil.ConvertTohex(b);
                wrapperId = h.SubString(0,8)+ '-' + h.SubString(8,12) + '-' + h.SubString(12,16) + '-' + h.SubString(16,20) + '-' + h.substring(20);
            }
        }
    }
```

Apex Page -

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!otlist}" var="otiWrap" id="table">
                    <apex:column  headerValue="Product">
                         <apex:inputfield value="{!otiWrap.odi.Product2Id}">
                             <apex:actionSupport action="{!productdetails}" event="onchange" reRender="table"/>
                        </apex:inputfield>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column  headerValue="Product Code">
                        <apex:inputfield value="{!otiWrap.odi.Product2.ProductCode}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column  headerValue="Quantity">
                        <apex:inputfield value="{!otiWrap.odi.Quantity}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column  headerValue="Unit Price">
                        <apex:inputfield value="{!otiWrap.odi.unitprice}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column  headerValue="Line Description">
                        <apex:inputfield value="{!otiWrap.odi.Description}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column  headerValue="Total Price">
                        <apex:inputfield value="{!otiWrap.odi.totalprice}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                   </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Comment: You don’t seem to be populating Product2 in your odi variable anywhere. And that may be reason while accessing wrapper.odi.Product2, you are getting the exception.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with actionsupport on vf page..i missed to pass apex:param wrapperid to the controller...This fixed the issue.

Below is the code which i have added to fix the issue -

```
<apex:actionSupport action="{!productdetails}" event="onchange" reRender="table">
    <apex:param name="wrapperId" value="{!otiWrap.wrapperId}" assignTo="{!changedPosRevWrapperId}" />
</apex:actionSupport>
```